# How to disable locking in LibreOffice?

Tags: files, libreoffice, lock

I want to disable file locking in LibreOffice, i.e., the creation of a hidden lock file in the directory of an opened document. The advice of the official documentation to comment out the second of the lines

```
SAL_ENABLE_FILE_LOCKING=1
export SAL_ENABLE_FILE_LOCKING
```

in `/usr/bin/soffice` (which is really a symbolic link targeting `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice`) does not help. The lock files are still created.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 which has LibreOffice 3.5.7.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To disable locking** open Terminal application, then copy, paste and execute following command.

***Notice***: it's one long command, 12 lines, starts with "echo" and ends with "disable-file-locking.xcd".

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oor:data xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry">
  <dependency file="main"/>
  <oor:component-data oor:package="org.openoffice.Office" oor:name="Common">
    <node oor:name="Misc">
      <prop oor:name="UseLocking">
        <value>false</value>
      </prop>
    </node>
  </oor:component-data>
</oor:data>' |
sudo tee /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/registry/disable-file-locking.xcd
```

**To undo changes**:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/registry/disable-file-locking.xcd
```

Comment: I know this is Ask Ubunutu, biut for googlers wondering about the same problem on macOS: the same recipe works using `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/registry/disable-file-locking.xcd`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`.

Add

```
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Misc"><prop oor:name="UseLocking" oor:op="fuse"><value>false</value></prop></item>
```

after the other `<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Misc">`

Comment: Make the change while all LO documents are closed. LO will rewrite its settings when we close a document.

Answer (score 1):

You can now change settings (even in Windows) from UI. [Source](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41442#c17)

> Since version 4.2, we have Expert Configuration feature allowing one to set different power-user settings from [...]
> **Options->LibreOffice->Advanced->Open Expert Configuration**. [...]
> `org.openoffice.Office.Common/Misc/UseLocking` setting
> (controlling creation of lockfiles and using locking in general), and `org.openoffice.Office.Common/Misc/UseDocumentOOoLockFile` setting
> (controlling whether the present lockfile will be considered when deciding if the file is locked by someone else).