# sharing files from Mac (ubuntu) to other mac machines

Tags: files, samba, mac, sharing

I am trying to set up a file sharing server with an old model mac mini that is running ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to share office documents from the mac mini (server) between other client mac machines.

i am having a frequent issue where the client machines are not able to open new office (word, excel etc) documents between each other.

i keep getting these frequent errors on the mac clients 'this file is locked for editing' and 'This document "x" could not be opened'. Has anyone encountered this error and/or have a solution?

all other files open fine, it is just Microsoft office documents that are giving this issue, i'm assuming its an office problem but if anyone could supply any info i would be very grateful.

Thank you

(apologies if i haven't been specific enough i am very tired and have been trying to solve this problem for almost a week now please let me know if any more info is needed)

Comment: Microsoft Office doesn't have an Ubuntu/Linux client so I'm not sure if this question is really on topic here.  This seems to be a problem with Office.  On the Microsoft support site have you seen the topic: [Unlock a file that has been locked for editing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unlock-a-file-that-has-been-locked-for-editing-bdda0d41-1b8e-44ed-a6ae-6d095d37c22d)

Answer (score 0):

Most document processors such as Microsoft word, or Libreoffice will create a hidden file whenever a document is opened for editing. This is file is used to indicate that the current file is already opened and being edited. When you try to open the same file, the hidden lock file is detected and the application won't allow you to continue.

I believe the only solution to this is to make sure you delete the lock file before attempting to open the same document for editing.

See: [How to disable locking in LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553824/how-to-disable-locking-in-libreoffice)

And: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unlock-a-file-that-has-been-locked-for-editing-bdda0d41-1b8e-44ed-a6ae-6d095d37c22d

Comment: thanks for your comment i have deleted the hidden files but it is still showing that it is locked for editing :(